# Logo spacing guidelines

Tags: typography, logo

I am currently working on our company's design guidelines (which is much needed). At the moment I am puzzling on how to use set-up the logo's spacing. Generally using the height of the first letter as our measurement is acceptable, which is normally a capital and also a sans-serif. Our logo, which is a by-product of the design-by-committee days, uses a serif type-face.

So my question is: Should I include the serifs in the spacing measurement?

**Without serifs in spacing:**
[image: Without Serif]

**With serifs in spacing:**
[image: with Serif]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer.. posed as a question...

If the logo were *not* text, would you clip part of it when considering spacing?

Don't let the fact that the logo happens to be a type glyph alter what you would do if it were not a glyph.

Factor in the serifs as well.

Comment: Thanks, that does make sense. Sometimes you can get so stuck on the theory that you forget basic logic.

Comment: Seconded. The bottom one is clearly the most elegant. I would say that if you should overlap letters in any way, then _overlap_ in a big(ger) way. Go all the way, or stay with sensible respect for letters :)

Comment: Hmm good point, lesson learned! :)